# Google Dataflow spending hours estimating input size

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm fairly new to Google Dataflow and I am finding that the service spends several hours estimating the input file size before actually processing data, and will often do several recounts for large input collections before failing.  I'm using Apache Beam 2.9 and the io.ReadFromText method.

The logs start with a comment about beginning estimation of input file size and continue to log an update every 10k files counted.

Is there a way to skip this step or to significantly increase the pace in which it does the count?

Comment: Looking into it. I'll try to answer by tomorrow : )

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple ReadFromText transforms that match a smaller subset of the files? E.g. changing `ReadFromText('gs://my_bucket/file*)` to `ReadFromText('gs://my_bucket/file0*)`, `ReadFromText('gs://my_bucket/file1*)`, `ReadFromText('gs://my_bucket/file2*)`,... etc?

Comment: This should help split the computation from the beigning and hopefully speed it up

Comment: FWIW how many files are there in your input?

Comment: I’ll give splitting the inputs up a try.  For the job we’re having trouble with there are around 10 million files.

Comment: I believe that this will turn out to be too much for a single Python source.  Splitting should help mitigate that issue. Hopefully that'll allow your pipeline to scale. In the future there will be `fileio` transforms that should scale better for those cases. I imagine that you have a good use case for Python here, but as a tip, Java should scale better for large file counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `ReadFromText` source is based on `FileBasedSource`. If you look at the code for it, you can find that [its estimate_size method is inefficient for a very large set of files](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.11.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py#L191-L194).

As we discussed in the comments, you may be able to improve this bottleneck by manually partitioning the range of files. For example, if your files are `gs://my_bucket/file001, gs://my_bucket/file002, ... gs://my_bucket/file999`, you should be able to add 10 sources, something like so:

```
p = Pipeline()
file_lines = (
  [p | ReadFromText('gs://my_bucket/file%s*' % i) for i in range(10)]
  | beam.Flatten())
```

This should help your pipeline scale for a case like this.

---

As for a permanent solution... I imagine that one could try to propose improvements to the source itself, so that a future version may have better performance.

There are also transforms based on Java's `FileIO` transforms that we are planning to implement. That may be helpful as well. But it's not so near in the horizon.